# How to setup an excel addin regression testing framework

Tags: excel-addins, regression-testing

I am writing some Excel addins at work in C++ in an XLL. Is there a standard and/or easy way to setup non regression tests for excel addins and integrate them with a source control software like SVN to produce automatic reports.

As BonCodigo mentioned, if I could call the addin via a C# program instead of from Excel it would make everything trivial.

I currently work with VS2005 and Office 2012.

Cheers
Tony

Comment: Well you could [call each Excel add-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725895/calling-an-excel-add-in-method-from-c-sharp-application-or-vice-versa) accordingly in a code written in VS2005 to generate the reports...

Comment: In the link you sent, the person is calling the addin from VBA, is there a way to call it via C# or VB.Net ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a pure C++ solution, you can use http://xll.codeplex.com and roll your own tests. The example below uses a macro called ensure that acts much like assert but throws a runtime error instead of calling abort. You could replace it with something that writes to a report (or the Event Log using xll/utility/log.h).

See, e.g., http://xllarray.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16920#136045